# What's the most convenient method to ensure that PostgreSQL 9.x hot standy replication is still functioning properly

Tags: postgresql, replication

Assuming that I've got it [hot server replication](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hot_Standby) all set up nicely, what's the easiest or most convenient steps I can take periodically to ensure that the hot server replication is still working fine and as it should be.

I thought of comparing `SELECT txid_current_snapshot();` on both servers. Is that good and safe enough to assume that replication is working fine if the 2 `txid`s match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's wiki has this information on its [page on streaming replication](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication#How_to_Use):

> You can calculate the replication lag by comparing the current WAL
>   write location on the primary with the last WAL location
>   received/replayed by the standby. They can be retrieved using
>   **pg_current_xlog_location** on the primary and the
>   **pg_last_xlog_receive_location / pg_last_xlog_replay_location** on the
>   standby, respectively.

In PostgreSQL version 10, these functions have been renamed to 
**`pg_current_wal_lsn`**, **`pg_last_wal_receive_lsn`** and **`pg_last_wal_replay_lsn`**, so the above names are now valid only for versions 9.6 and older.

These functions return a string of the form `id/offset` where `id` and `offset` are hexadecimal numbers. To convert them to 64 bit numbers for comparison purposes, you may use this formula, taken from the [check_postgres](https://github.com/bucardo/check_postgres/blob/master/check_postgres.pl) Nagios plugin:

```
0xff000000 * from_hex(id) + from_hex(offset)
```

In a bash script, it can be done with this function:

```
xlog_location_to_64bits()
{
  id="${1%%/*}"
  offset="${1##*/}"
  echo $((0xFF000000 * 0x$id + 0x$offset))
}
```

Subtracting the value on the slave from the value on the master gives the replication lag in bytes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's very helpful. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most convenient method would be what is mentioned at [step 12 of this page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication#How_to_Use):

```
# The displayed LSNs indicate the byte position that the standby server has
# written up to in the xlogs.
[primary] $ ps -ef | grep sender
postgres  6879  6831  0 10:31 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal sender process postgres    127.0.0.1(44663) streaming 0/2000000

[standby] $ ps -ef | grep receiver
postgres  6878  6872  1 10:31 ?        00:00:01 postgres: wal receiver process   streaming 0/2000000
```